# I can't click and navigate to another page using Button() and NavigationLink()

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

**I have the following code segment to navigate to another page once "Logout" text or "logout" icon has been triggered:**

```
         //$tempSignout is a boolean var -> @State  var tempSignout = false

        NavigationLink(destination:   SigninView(), isActive: $tempSignout) {EmptyView()}
       
        Button(action: {
            tempSignout = true
        }, label: {
            HStack{
                Text("Logout")
                    .underline()
                    .foregroundColor(Color("logoutColor"))
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                    .padding(.trailing, -100)
                
                
                Image("logout").resizable()
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    .padding(.leading, 100)
            }
            
            
        })
```

**And here's the UI that represents the above code segment:**

[image]

**The issue is: I can't navigate to the targeted page whether I press the logout text or icon, it seems not clickable at all.**

Comment: it would be best to show us a minimal reproducible code, that shows your issue. Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping all your contents inside a **NavigationView** because without a NavigationView, navigating does not work.

```
NavigationView {
//all your contents, stacks, buttons, etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to work properly you need to wrap the whole view body in a Navigation view. E.g.

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    struct BananasView: View {
        var body: some View {
            Text("Bananas")
                .navigationTitle("")
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: BananasView()) {
                Text("I want bananas!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example from https://swiftontap.com/navigationlink. A good resource to understand this is [Navigation Link Tutorial](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/displaying-a-detail-screen-with-navigationlink)